# Turning music on piano so it doesn't fold

Tags: piano, books

My piano teacher lent me some books that are very old and expensive. My piano has a little dip down that holds the music, but when I turn the page, the bottom of the page drags along the top of the dip and folds/ripples the page. I don't want to damage these books, so how would I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Technology! Scan it and load it into a tablet like the new iPad 3! Place the tablet on the dip in your piano... and lo, u can just tap to turn!

Answer (score 10):

If you could make photocopies of the pieces you need without damaging the books (the spine, most likely), that would probably be best.

Comment: Be careful not to press the book too hard when copying. This can also damage the spine.

Comment: Libraries often have scanners that can copy a page when it is only open at 90 degrees - this helps protect the spine of a valuable book.

Answer (score 0):

There are also music book clips you can buy. Here is an example of one from Amazon.com [music book clip](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000M74WXM)

Comment: A clip wouldn't work if the book was hardcover. Even if the book was paperback, it could still damage the bind. Besides, how would you flip the pages quickly?

Answer (score 0):

My dad improvised a shelf-extension for my piano with a bent sheet of aluminum. You could make one with a slight rise at the edge instead of a lip. Cost of materials is quite low, but an aluminum bender is a very large and pricey tool.